# Find a relation between $v_{n}$ and $v_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

Let us consider the sequence $v_{n}$ defined by: $$v_{n}=∑_{i=3}^{n}d_{i}∏_{j=i+1}^{n}a_{j}$$ where $d_{i}$ and $a_{j}$ are two real sequences.

My **question** is: Find a relation between $v_{n}$ and $v_{n-1}$.

My **attempt**: I can find the relation between the first terms but I am not able to generalized the obtained formula.

Comment: What are $d_i$ and $a_j$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: $d_{i}$ and $a_{j}$ are two real sequences.

Comment: Maybe $v_n = a_{n}v_{n-1} + d_n$.

Comment: @M.T: How you get that!

Comment: $v_n = a_n(\sum_{i=3}^{n-1}d_i\prod_{j=i+1}^{n-1}a_j) + d_n$.

Comment: I think something is wrong, take i=n, please correct your problem.